# Game class not calling other classes

Tags: java, game-development, pong

I am new to java code that is fresh code (I used to make minecraft mods) and I am trying to create a simple pong game. I have everything I believe I need for the game to play properly however it seems that the main game class is not calling the other classes when I need it to. Is there anything wrong here that you can see that I am missing? It would be a really great help.

Main Game Class

```
package crim.pong.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel{


    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xa = 1;
    int ya = 1;

    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    Racquet racquet = new Racquet(this);
    private void moveBall(){
        ball.move();
        racquet.move();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
        ball.paint(g2d);
        racquet.paint(g2d);

}

    public void gameOver(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.exit(ABORT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while(true){
            game.moveBall();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

    }
}
```

---

Keyboard class

```
package crim.pong.main;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyboardInput extends JPanel{
    public KeyboardInput(){
        KeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener();
        addKeyListener(listener);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        KeyboardInput keyboardInput = new KeyboardInput();
        frame.add(keyboardInput);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener{
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            System.out.println("keyReleased="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
        }
    }

}
```

---

Ball class

```
package crim.pong.main;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Ball {

    private static final int DIAMETER = 30;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xa = 1;
    int ya = 1;
    private Game game;

    public Ball(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    } 

    void move(){
        if(x + xa < 0)
            xa = 1;
        if(x + xa > game.getWidth() - DIAMETER)
            xa = -1;
        if(y + ya < 0)
            ya = 1;
        if(y + ya > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER)
            game.gameOver();
            if(collision()){
                ya = -1;
                y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
            }


        x = x - xa;
        y = y - ya;
    }

        private boolean collision(){
            return game.racquet.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
        }
    public void paint(Graphics2D g){
        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    }
    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }
}
```

---

Racquet class

```
package crim.pong.main;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Racquet {
    private static final int Y = 330;
    private static final int WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 20;
    int x = 0;
    int xa = 0;
    private Game game;

    public Racquet(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void move(){
        if(x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth() - 60)
            x = xa + xa;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g){
        g.fillRect(x, 330, 60, 10);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        xa = 0;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            xa = -1;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            xa = 1;
    }
    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
    public int getTopY(){
        return Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: Please format code, and provide a minimal example.

Comment: The problem description is quite vague too. "the main game class is not calling the other classes when I need it to", is it related to the keyboard class, the game class? No one is going to copy your entire program and start debugging it

Comment: *"Is there anything wrong here"* - You violating the single threaded nature of Swing; rather than using a `while-loop` as you main loop, consider using a Swing `Timer`; You're using `KeyListener`, instead, consider using the Key Bindings API

Comment: `Game` works, it shows stuff, but `KeyboardInput` doesn't because, well, it doesn't do anything anyway (you have two `main` methods, so it's confusing)

Comment: You need to change the way you think about this. You have a number of important concepts to deal with.  First of all, you have "state", the state of the entities, the state of the input, other "game states" (like the score), this information should be managed through some kind of model (and submodels as required), this represents a "virtual" view of your game. You then have the "render" whose job it is to render the state of the model. You have the "main loop" whose job it is to schedule time for updating the model state and scheduling the rendering. Input should feed the model

Comment: in  terms of the output its just displaying the ball and the racquet theres no animation or movement, ill have a look in a the code again guys thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you have 2 main class files. This is wrong.

A class with a 'main' function is the entry point of the program and obviously there can be only one entry point and presumably you have set this as 'Game'.

KeyboardInput should also not try to create a new JFrame. You only need one and it should be created by your 'Game' class.

If you want to keep the keyboard input in a seperate class then you want 'KeyboardInput' to implement KeyListener directly and then add it to the jframe created by 'Game', e.g.
(In 'Game')

```
KeyboardInput listener = new KeyboardInput();
addKeyListener(listener);
```

(In 'KeyboardInput')

```
public class KeyboardInput implements KeyListener
{
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    //... etc etc
```